# ExtJS On/Off Button

Tags: button, extjs, extjs3, togglebutton

I want to create mobile like on/off button with extjs in my web application. I couldn't find any sample or solution for this. I want actually like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/johniehjelm/zAVqU/4/)**

**CSS**

```
/* 
    Created by @JohnieHjelm. I took the liberty of doing this ON/OFF switch
    just to express my love for CSS3. You're free to use this and of course
    I hoped you learned something. Sharing is Caring♥
*/

body{
    background:#eee;
}

ul{
    list-style:none;
    width:85px;
    height:26px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin:-13px 0 0 -42px;
}

ul li{
    float:left;
    line-height:23px;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:2px 10px 0; 

    background: #E5E5E5;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#F3F3F3), to(#E5E5E5));
    text-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF;
    border-left:1px solid #D5D5D5;
    border-top:1px solid #D5D5D5;
    border-bottom:1px solid #D5D5D5;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 0 #FFF inset, 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) inset, 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

ul li:first-child{
    -webkit-border-radius:5px 0 0 5px;
}
ul li:last-child{
    -webkit-border-radius:0 5px 5px 0;
}

ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:Helvetica, Arial;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:#a1a1a1;
}

.on{
    background: #505050;
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#777), to(#505050));
    text-shadow:0 -1px 0 #444, 0 0 7px #9AE658;
    border-right:1px solid #444;
    border-top:1px solid #444;
    border-bottom:1px solid #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7) inset, 0 1px 0 #FFF;  
}

ul li:not(.on):active{
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#ddd), to(#f1f1f1));
}


ul li.on a{
    color:#7BBA47;
    cursor: default;
}​
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $("ul li").click(function(){
        $("ul li").removeClass("on");
        $(this).addClass("on"); 
    });
});​
```

How can I do this with ExtJS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a quick one which can easily extended to a full component:

```
Ext.get(Ext.query("ul li")).on('click', function(e, t, eOpts) { 
    var el = Ext.get(this),p;
    el.addCls("on");
    if((p = el.next())) {
        p.removeCls("on");
        alert('can fire turn OFF');
    } else if ((p = el.prev())){
        p.removeCls("on");
        alert('can fire turn ON');
    }
})​;​
```

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zAVqU/697/)**